# How to get all bookmarks in PDF file using PDFBox in Java

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am newbie in Apache PDFbox. I want to extract all bookmarks in PDF file using PDFBox library in Java. Any idea how to extract them?

Answer (score 10):

From the [PrintBookmarks example](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/PrintBookmarks.java?view=markup&sortby=date) in the source code download

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("..."));
PDDocumentOutline outline =  document.getDocumentCatalog().getDocumentOutline();
printBookmark(outline, "");
document.close();
```

(...)

```
public void printBookmark(PDOutlineNode bookmark, String indentation) throws IOException
{
    PDOutlineItem current = bookmark.getFirstChild();
    while (current != null)
    {
        System.out.println(indentation + current.getTitle());
        printBookmark(current, indentation + "    ");
        current = current.getNextSibling();
    }
}
```

Comment: I also had to get the page number.

`PDPage currentPage = current.findDestinationPage(document)
            Integer pageNumber = document.documentCatalog.pages.indexOf(currentPage) + 1`