# How to select pdf page using bookmark in pdf box?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Sorry i am new to PDF box and was looking for a solution on how to get a specific pdf page using the bookmark name? Like the below code snippet am trying to loop all the pages but stuck to link the book mark with the page i need. Can any one please help?

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.InvalidPasswordException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.documentnavigation.destination.PDPageFitWidthDestination;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.documentnavigation.outline.PDDocumentOutline;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.documentnavigation.outline.PDOutlineItem;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.documentnavigation.outline.PDOutlineNode;

public class PDFLoader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidPasswordException, IOException, PrinterException {


          File file = new File("d:\\pdf\\sample.pdf"); 
          PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file); 
          PDPage page01 = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);
          PDPage page02 = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(1);

          PDDocumentOutline outline =  document.getDocumentCatalog().getDocumentOutline();
          printBookmark(outline, "");
          PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
          doc.addPage(page01);
          doc.addPage(page02);
          doc.save("d:\\pdf\\newSample.pdf");
          doc.close();

    }



public static PDPage getBookmark(PDOutlineNode bookmark, String indentation) throws IOException
    {
        PDOutlineItem current = bookmark.getFirstChild();
        while (current != null)

        {
            System.out.println(indentation + current.getTitle());



            if (current.getAction() instanceof PDActionGoTo)
            {
                PDActionGoTo gta = (PDActionGoTo) current.getAction();
                if (gta.getDestination() instanceof PDPageDestination)
                {

                    if(current.getTitle().equals("MyBookMark")){


                        PDPageDestination pd = (PDPageDestination) current.getDestination();
                        System.out.println("Destination page: " + pd.retrievePageNumber());
                        return pd.getPage();

                        }
                }
            }

            getBookmark(current, indentation + "    ");
            current = current.getNextSibling();

            }


        return null;
    }







//Stack Trace
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mypackage.PDFLoader.getBookmark(PDFLoader.java:67)
    at com.mypackage.PDFLoader.main(PDFLoader.java:40)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all bookmarks in PDF file using PDFBox in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35260456/how-to-get-all-bookmarks-in-pdf-file-using-pdfbox-in-java)

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358472/how-to-get-the-pagenumber-of-the-content-of-a-bookmark-in-a-pdf-with-pdfbox

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I have updated the  code above and tried getting the page using bookmark. However am getting nullpointer exception for destination.getPage(); . Can you please help or suggest if am i missing any link?

Comment: Please link to the PDF (or any PDF) that you are using, also add enough code so that I can see where you're getting it. Also replace PDPageFitWidthDestination with PDPageDestination to avoid classcastexceptions.

Comment: I have updated the code section and posted the full class which i am trying to run. I believe am passing the PDDocumentOutline object to getBookMark(outline, "") method to link my pdf so not sure that is right or am i missing anything? Please suggest.

Comment: I need the PDF... I tried with another PDF that has bookmarks and it worked. Alternatively, tell me what PDFBox version you're using (should be 2.0.6) and edit your question to include the stack trace. I'll look in the source code of `retrievePageNumber()` to see if there's a bug (assuming I understand correctly that the bug is there). Ping me again (to be sure it works, put "@Tilman Hausherr") when done.

Comment: Also add a check that `current.getDestination()` is not null. It can be null!

Comment: @Tilman Hausher I added the stack trace in the code section which is just three lines pointing to getPages or retrievePageNumber methods. I am using 2.0.6 version. Not sure how I can share my PDF here i tried searching options but no luck?

Comment: I am amazed how it is working for you but not for me. Did you try my source code on your sample pdf? I am not sure if you have noticed, it is getting the bookmark and going inside the if condition but when it tries to invoke the retrievePageNumber or getPage method it is throwing off with null pointer..

Comment: You didn't add a null check... even better, add something like this:  `if (current.getDestination() instanceof PDPageDestination)` . Anyway, the stack trace shows it doesn't happen in `retrievePageNumber()`, I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: I've just updated the example, see https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/PrintBookmarks.java?view=markup&sortby=date  at the bottom, maybe that makes it more clear.

Comment: And here's the file I used for test: http://wikisend.com/download/663326/000009.pdf

Comment: see answer and / or updated sample code from earlier comment. Btw your code went NPE because you didn't check the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in your PDF the page destination is not in the bookmark's destination entry, but in the bookmark's action entry (yes, PDF makes it possible to have two ways to do the same thing). Add this to your code:

```
if (current.getDestination() instanceof PDPageDestination)
{
    PDPageDestination pd = (PDPageDestination) current.getDestination();
    System.out.println("Destination page: " + (pd.retrievePageNumber() + 1));
    return pd.getPage();
}
if (current.getAction() instanceof PDActionGoTo)
{
    PDActionGoTo gta = (PDActionGoTo) current.getAction();
    if (gta.getDestination() instanceof PDPageDestination)
    {
        PDPageDestination pd = (PDPageDestination) gta.getDestination();
        System.out.println("Destination page: " + (pd.retrievePageNumber() + 1));
        return pd.getPage();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tim Hausherr Thanks for that suggestion sorry it didn't worked. I have updated the code above for getBookMark method which i tried but getting the same result as null pointer :(

Comment: That is because your code has `current.getDestination()`. Replace that with `gta.getDestination()`. Btw the current code of yours would work only with that file, not with mine. The code I have would work with both.

Comment: Yap it works great now. I have checked mark your above answer. Thank you so much!