# How to extract the nested bookmark which are under the header bookmark

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

This is a strange situation. I am working on a pdf file where there is only one bookmark name but under this bookmark there are like 42 bookmarks nested or sub bookmarks. I am not sure how I can extract this as I do not see any options for that available. Though I have posted this question to the pdf box team but no reply yet. Can any one please suggest any option or solution? Below is the structure of the bookmarks in my pdf

```
MainBookMarkName
|_firstBookMark (1-10 pages)
|_secondBookMark (1-5 pages)
|_thirdBookMark (1-8 pages)
|_FourthBookMark (1-15 pages)
|_
|_
|_lastBookMark (42)
```

The below code just loads the "MainBookMarkName" and prints all the nested bookmarks but is not looping each of them or extracting any of them. All the pages are associated with only nested bookmarks not the main one.

```
//Trying to access step1 or step 2 sub book marks and then get their pages but those sub marks am unable to access individually.

How to “Combine Files into a PDF” using Acrobat Pro
    Step 1: Organize Your Activity Files & Create a Table of Contents
    Step 2: Open Adobe Acrobat Pro.
    Step 3: Add Files
    Step 4: Arrange Files in Final Order
Step 5: Combine Files to Finalize the Document




public static PDPage printBookmark(PDDocument document, PDOutlineNode bookmark, String indentation) throws IOException
        {
            PDOutlineItem current = bookmark.getFirstChild();
           PDOutlineItem subBookMark =  current.getFirstChild();


            while( subBookMark!= null )
            {
                System.out.println(subBookMark.getTitle());

                if (subBookMark.getDestination() instanceof PDPageDestination)
                {

                   if(subBookMark.getTitle().equals("SubBookMark10")){


                       PDPageDestination pd = (PDPageDestination) subBookMark.getDestination();
                        System.out.println("Destination page: " + (pd.retrievePageNumber() + 1));

                        return pd.getPage();

                        }
                }

                printBookmark( document, current, indentation + "    " );
               subBookMark = subBookMark.getNextSibling();
            }
            return null;

        }




 //Trying to access step1 or step 2 sub book marks and then get their pages but those sub marks am unable to access individually.

How to “Combine Files into a PDF” using Acrobat Pro
    Step 1: Organize Your Activity Files & Create a Table of Contents
    Step 2: Open Adobe Acrobat Pro.
    Step 3: Add Files
    Step 4: Arrange Files in Final Order
Step 5: Combine Files to Finalize the Document
```

Comment: I am part of the PDFBox team and I don't see any question of yours, and there's no post in moderation... could you upload your PDF to a sharehoster? I'll have a look at it. Note that the PrintBookmarks example has been updated yesterday to support GoToAction destinations, see https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/PrintBookmarks.java?view=markup&sortby=date . And I don't understand what you mean with "but is not looping each of them or extracting any of them".

Comment: Thanks for your response. The bookmark name "MainBookMarkName" has nested bookmarks or sub bookmarks under it and am not able to extract it. The bookmark.getFirstChild(); gets only "MainBookMarkName" but not the 42 bookmarks which are under it. I hope this information helps? Can you refer to the PDF structure I listed above.

Comment: Actually I have emailed my question on this email address  users-info@pdfbox.apache.org

Comment: That address doesn't exist. The addresses are here: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pdfbox-users/ Re your other comment, I really need the file, I still don't understand you, sorry. There could be all sort of reasons why it doesn't work. Alternatively, if the file is confidential, work with the two files mentioned in the comments of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982486 (see "wikisend" links).

Comment: Will the image or screen shot of the bookmark works? I tried to upload the image on wikisend but it is not loading up there.

Comment: . I got a sample file from online which have the bookmarks similar to my file I can share that. The wikisend seems to have issues in uploading the file for me. Is there any way I can share this file with you?

Comment: send to tilman at snafu dot de, or upload to filedropper.com

Comment: Thanks! Uploaded the file here http://www.filedropper.com/mysamplefile

Comment: I am actually referring to the bookmark "How to “Combine Files into a PDF” using Acrobat Pro" under which there are sub bookmarks. I am unable to get the pages for those sub bookmarks as I cannot loop in or access those sub bookmarks.

Comment: It works with the PDFBox sample... I tested with your code too, the pages are missing because you have the same problem as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982486 . The pages are in the destinations of GoToAction entries. Use the code that starts with `if (current.getAction() instanceof PDActionGoTo)`

Comment: @Tim Hausherr I guess it works fine now. I believe we need to extract the sub bookmark using the main book mark object by invoking the getFirstChild() method and then move it to next one by using getNextSibling() method.  Thanks anyway your support and suggestions were helpful

Comment: I'm back... the code I was using was the one I mentioned in my first comment. I haven't understood your late problem, the iterating was part of the code. Anyway, either answer it yourself, or delete the question.

Comment: Thanks. I will update the code above shortly so that it can be helpful to others in the future. One important question not sure I should use this thread or need to create the another one. The is question is how can I identify the pages which are under the sub book mark? I mean sub book mark has 1-10 pages how can I pick the 6th page? Is their any identifier function or option to pick the specific page as these pages under sub book mark do not have any identification what I see.

Comment: Please create a new issue for that, it would make it all even more complex. And again I don't understand you... to take a bookmark from a level just call `current.getNextSibling();` a few times... Maybe the problem is that you get confused by the recursion? (i.e. that printBookmark calls itself)

Comment: I have updated the code section with my answer. Coming to your question, yes I have a little complex pdf to parse which have bookmark pretty complicated. I have edited the pdf structure above which could make it clear which was trying to ask about. Please refer here MainBookMarkName
|_firstBookMark (1-10 pages)

Comment: Your file has only 24 pages.

Comment: MainBookMarkName |_firstBookMark (1-10 pages)  . How can I access these pages as there is no identifier like bookmark for these pages.

Comment: The file I am working on is confidential, the one I shared is the sample one from online. :)

Comment: You can access pages directly. `document.getPage(pageNo);`

Comment: Sorry I have updated the pdf structure section. Actually each sub book mark has pages starts from (1-10) (1-15) etc. Please refer above. Not sure if document.getPage(pageNo) will work as this pages are at sub bookmark level?

Comment: Please create a new question, attach a link to your pdf, include your code and explain what you want and what happened instead.

Comment: Sure. Thank you!

Comment: @Joe Please do not answer inside your question but use an actual answer. As it is now, your question still is counted and displayed as unanswered by stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer for extracting the sub bookmarks.

```
   public static PDPage printBookmark(PDDocument document, PDOutlineNode bookmark, String indentation) throws IOException
            {
                PDOutlineItem current = bookmark.getFirstChild();
               PDOutlineItem subBookMark =  current.getFirstChild();


                while( subBookMark!= null )
                {
                    System.out.println(subBookMark.getTitle());

                    if (subBookMark.getDestination() instanceof PDPageDestination)
                    {

                       if(subBookMark.getTitle().equals("SubBookMark10")){


                           PDPageDestination pd = (PDPageDestination) subBookMark.getDestination();
                            System.out.println("Destination page: " + (pd.retrievePageNumber() + 1));

                            return pd.getPage();

                            }
                    }

                    printBookmark( document, current, indentation + "    " );
                   subBookMark = subBookMark.getNextSibling();
                }
                return null;

            }
```

Comment: weird... your "subbookmark" is what you get by skipping a level. You had that "subbookmark" before too, due to the recursive nature of the code. And you'll miss the subbookmarks of the second child.

Comment: I have a weird pdf as it has a very complex structure I don't know why. Due to the complex structure of our pdf we are analyzing it is valid enough to use the API's like pdf box or any other one.